# Period in RESTful WCF Starter Kit

Tags: wcf, rest

I am using RESTful WFC's WebInvoke and WebGet attribute classes.  In the UriTemplate parameter I want to capture a variable which includes the period character.  How do I do so?

So

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "{id}")]
[OperationContract]
TItem UpdateItemInXml(string id, TItem newValue);
```

I would like it to match the url: 
    http://service.svc/A.1

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do so.  The solution I implemented was to base64 encode the id in the URL.